# How do I catch generic fault exceptions in Fitnesse?

Tags: fitnesse

Previously within my Fitnesse fixture I was specifying an expected WCF exception using:

```
exception[FaultException]
```

Since then I have converted the WCF service to return a strongly typed FaultContract.  I am now getting the following failure message:

```
exception[FaultException`1: "A file with the name DMS Documents/testFileWord.doc already exists. It was last modified by SHAREPOINT\system on 09 Mar 2010 15:36:14 -0000."]
```

This is not unexpected but how do I check for strongly typed fault exceptions?  Please note I cannot include the fault message as part of the check as it contains a date which changes (I check this separately).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the exception name that's being generated: exception[FaultException`1]

I've added an issue to use the full generic type name if the exception type is generic. http://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp/issues/issue/44

Comment: That worked, funny I was sure I tried that.  Thanks for submitting the issue having the full generic type would be a big improvement.